# OR Condition - true if AND would apply?

Tags: conditional-statements

Imagine you have the following sentences:

1. I am happy.
2. I am very cool.
3. I am very happy.

You're looking for a sentence that satisfies the following condition:

```
NOT(very OR happy)
```

It's clear that nor sentence 1 nor sentence 2 satisfies this condition. However, does sentence 3 satisfy this condition? Since it doesn't contain "very OR happy", but "very AND happy".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about discrete mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

It is satisfying the condition 3 as well ie, it contains both. "very OR happy" is also true and "very AND happy" is also true.

In the logical statement if out of the two statements in OR condition the first is `true` and the next statement is not evaluated. However in case of AND if the first statement evaluates to false then the next statement is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The OR condition for a and b means at least one of them is true.

I am very happy.
Very = true, Happy = true

Put that into NOT(very OR happy) gives you:

```
NOT(true OR true)
```

Which is equal to:

```
NOT(true)
```

Which is equal to:

```
false
```